# Size of text in viewport is different in render

Tags: rendering

I'm new to blender! I have a problem that I can't seem to solve.
The tracked text seems to change size when I render it, for some reason it's bigger. I don't know what went wrong. Rendered in with Eevee render engine. This will eventually be rendered as an animation. I have a screenshot:
[image]

Is there anything else I should screenshot?

Comment: Are you able to show the render vs what you have in the editor?  Is this a file you are willing to share?

Comment: Do you need the rendered animation vs what I have in the viewport display? How do I share the blender file? @Kirbinator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to fix it! So I put the resolution at 65% in 1920 by 1080 and it now matches the viewport!